# How to browse a file using iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to develop an app for universal ios device. in that i want to browse the files(if any) available on device. Can any one let me know how to do this any examples,methods or suggestions. what methods should i call for this.

help me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at NSHomeDirectory() and NSFileManager, and there's no way to access all files on device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not let users browse system files available on the device in an app. From what I can understand, you want to create an app like ifile which is a jailbreak app that requires a jailbroken device to function and remove the restriction Apple places on apps. Thus on a stock Apple device, this app would not work.